# Salesforce Data Event - is this right?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, marketing-cloud-connect

We are configuring Journey Builder for a client using Salesforce Data Events as Entry, more specifically we want to use the Account object.

When configuring the Entry Source, we see that for the Account object we only have these 3 options in the "Select who to inject into the journey":

[image]

The documentation only states:
"To specify who enters the journey, such as leads or contacts, choose a Sales or Service Cloud object as the source of the entry event"

- Select when the person enters the journey, such as when a record is
  created or updated.
- Select attributes from object data to filter who
  enters the journey.
- Select fields from related objects

It does not specify which fields should appear at this point or at least any recommendation. I tried with all three, and when testing the journey (activating it, rather, as there is no Test button available when using SF Data as Entry Source) only 1 registry was injected from about 50.000 contacts.

SFDC synchronization is working correctly as all the needed objects are being synchronized.

Not sure what other pieces of info I could provide, but if anyone has any idea of what is going on please go ahead.

Thanks!

Comment: Who is the anticipated audience? Are you using person accounts? Why would you want to use an account for the entry audience? I can probably provide a good answer if you give this info!

Comment: The only "Sendable Objects" (Human Beings) from a Marketing Cloud standpoint are Contacts, Leads and Users. You can use (more or less) any SObject as the basis for an entry event to Journey Builder, so long has it has a lookup field to one of the Sendable Objects. Person Accounts have a PersonContactId field that makes this type of Account frequently seen in Entry Events in Journey Builder. For classic Accounts in a B2C setting, there's not much use for an Account as an Entry Event, unless you want to communicate with the Account Owner, maybe.

Comment: Thanks @NateHarris, the thing is our client is not using Leads, because they dont have a Lead process. They use accounts. Macca: I was able to talk to SF Support and they mentioned exactly the same, so we crated a Data Extension from a Query and used that as Entry Source for our Journey.